# MySQL bug? Select WHERE id='1blah'

Tags: mysql, select

MySQL Version 5.0.67

Take a look at this very simple table and tell me if I have found a MySQL bug, I have tried to search for an answer but as you can imagine it's a bit hard to come up with the right search terms

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `product` VALUES (1, 'jim');
INSERT INTO `product` VALUES (2, 'bob');
```

From there I can then select the following

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = '1';
```

Obviously this returns a row, but then, so does this

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = '1blah';
```

Erm... WHY?  Surely this is wrong or am I going mad?  Will crawl the web a bit more before I file a bug report with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of type conversion. Since your column has integer value, '1blah' is converted to 1. Please, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html for more details.

Comment: Ah that explains it, okay so now to find out how to stop it, I don't want this :)  I think BINARY() may be the way

Comment: @Catharsis - That's not what BINARY is for. Irrespective, you should really fix this in your SQL query construction code, not in the query itself.

Comment: @Catharsis: you could use `CAST(id as TEXT)`, but then you'd lose the ability to use the index on `id` in the query.

Comment: Thanks I was going to do that as well, but I was hoping I could re-inforce it using MySQL, maybe not though

Answer (score 5):

It's automatically converting the string "1blah" into an integer. As the string begins with a "1" the resultant integer is simply 1.

As such, it's just trying to do the right thing, even though it might seem a bit counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't enclose the integer id in quotes, it'd work *and* you'd get an error as you'd hope. That is,

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = 1;

1 row in set
```

works, while

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = 1blah;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '1blah' in 'where clause'
```

errors.

Comment: True, I might have to put something in my PHP class to ensure only strings get quoted

Comment: @Catharsis - If this is coming from a custom PHP class, make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string for *all* variables.